# PHP: why year not subtracted from date?

Tags: php, date, datetime, subtraction

The below code doesn't subtract 1 year from the date. Why?

```
$date1 = '2021-06-02';
$date2 = new \DateTime(date($date1, strtotime('-1 year')));
echo $date2->format('Y-m-d'); // outputs the same date 2021-06-02
```

Comment: You are using the DateTime Class so this should help - https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code. Its always works for me.

```
$date1 = '2021-06-02';
$date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 year", strtotime($date1)));
echo $date2; //Output 2020-06-02
```

This is for Date time object:

```
$dt = new DateTime('2021-06-02');
$minusOneYearDT = $dt->sub(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
$minusOneYear = $minusOneYearDT->format('Y-m-d');    
echo $minusOneYear;
```

OR make a small solution:

```
$time = new DateTime('2021-06-02');
$newtime = $time->modify('-1 year')->format('Y-m-d');
echo $newtime;
```

Comment: yep, that works. Thank you! Why doesn't my code work I wonder?..

Comment: Please check my answer for date object.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is that the `date` function's first argument is the format of the date.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

So what is happening is that you are creating a date string with the format of '2021-06-02'.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

This doesn't use anything from the timestamp that you are providing so this string is passed to the constructor of DateTime and creating the date instead of the one from the year previous.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit of a muddle:

- [date()](https://php.net/date) takes as parameters a format string, and an integer representing a point in time; it then applies the format to create a string for that date and time
- [strtotime()](https://php.net/strtotime) takes a string, interprets it as a point in time, and returns an integer timestamp
- [new DateTime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) takes a string, in any of the formats `strtotime` would accept, but creates an object representation rather than returning an integer

You've tried to use all of them at once, and got in a mess:

- Your call to `date()` has a first parameter of '2021-06-02', which isn't a valid format.
- Your call to `strtotime()` has a parameter of '-1 year', which will just be interpreted as "1 year before now", not relative to anything else you've specified.
- Using both of those functions and then passing to `new \DateTime()` doesn't make a lot of sense, since the object can do all the same things those functions can do.

If you want to use the integer-based functions, you could write this:

```
$date1 = '2021-06-02';
$date2 = strtotime("$date1 -1 year");
echo date('Y-m-d', $date2);
```

If you want to use the object-based functions, you could write this:

```
$date1 = '2021-06-02';
$date2 = new \DateTime("$date1 -1 year");
echo $date2->format('Y-m-d');
```

Or this (note the use of [DateTimeImmutable](https://php.net/DateTimeImmutable) instead of `DateTime` to avoid the `modify` method changing the `$date1` object:

```
$date1 = new \DateTimeImmutable('2021-06-02');
$date2 = $date1->modify('-1 year');
echo $date2->format('Y-m-d');
```